# Rails 4.2 strange error Association named 'user' was not found on Link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, model-associations

I have models with relationship like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :identities
 has_many :activities

end

class Identity < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :user
 has_many :manifests
 has_many :activities, through: :manifests

end

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :user
 has_one :link
 has_many :manifests
 has_many :identities, through: :manifests

end

class Manifest < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :activity
 belongs_to :identity

end

class Link < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :activity

end
```

But when I try to call

```
 user.activities
```

it raise an error

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError: Association named 'user' was    not found on Link; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

It got me confused as I don't put user relationship on Link model. Can someone help me?

Comment: Does activities table has user_id as foreign key?  You might not have specified the association.
If you don't have the association at the db level, then create a new migration with something like:
  def change
   add_reference :activities, :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end

Comment: yes, activities table has user_id as fk

Comment: I cannot re-pruduce this https://github.com/maxcal/sandbox/tree/31063937. I'm guessing the error is might be that your `user` variable is not a User at all. Try using `abort user.class.name`  to verify.

Comment: how you are getting `user`?

Comment: User.first, I tried it on console. After messing around, I think foreign key constraint on database may caused it. Or rails have bug over it. I tried to debug it on active record gem and I found error when calling link objects. It strange as I don't write include on query. The link object try to get user as parent. I found it really strange.

Comment: @ihsanoeddin what exactly you want? Activities of a particular user?

Comment: @test, user's activities. The problem is solved though, I drop my database and migrate again without foreign key constraint and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :identities
 has_many :activities
 has_many :links, through: :activities

end

class Link < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :activity
 belongs_to :user, through: :activity

end
```

Why? In this case we should make complied join tables `users`, `activities` and `links`.

Comment: thanks,  but I solved it by removing foreign key constraints on database